# Fourier expansion for boolean function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, boolean-algebra

What is the Fourier expansion for $\text{maj}_4=\{-1,+1\}^4$? I know the empty set coefficient is $0$ but not sure about the rest. Thoughts?